# Adding new Facts to database PROLOG

Tags: prolog

Suppose that I have 3 nodes  A,B, and C and there are edge between A and B and between B and C. I want to assert a new fact to database during run time, so that if an there is an edge between A and B and another edge from B to C then I can reach from A to C. I want the edge(a,c) to be added but I have the following problems, Thanks in Advance

```
dynamic/1: No permission to modify static procedure `edge/2' 
ERROR: [Thread pce] c:/users/win7/documents/prolog/test.pl:6: Syntax error:      Operator expected
```

this is my code:

```
edge(a,b).
edge(b,c).

:- dynamic edge/2.

conn :-(X,C):- edge(X,Y),edge(Y,C),assert(edge(X,C)).
```

Comment: `conn :-(X,C):- ...` is a syntax error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally it works,

:- dynamic edge/2.
edge(a,b).
edge(b,c).

conn(X,Y,C) :- edge(X,Y),edge(Y,C),assert( edge(X,C)).

Answer (score 3):

The `dynamic` declaration must come first, before you defined clauses for `edge/2`.